# "commands commence before first target" error in a makefile

Tags: makefile

I read many questions which are similar to this one, but I could not find any good answers.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_XSLT=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\" -DUNIX_SOCKETS -DXML_SECURITY -DDEBUG
LDFLAGS= -lcrypto -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -I/usr/local/include/xmlsec1 -lxmlsec1 -lprotobuf-c

$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) src/main.c src/file1.c src/file3.pb-c.c -o   fileClient
```

This one is my make files. All three header files are in the `src` directory. The `.c` files are also in the `src` directory.

Dependencies Libraries:

- openssl 0.9.8 or above
- libxml
- xmlsec1 1.2.9 or above (if digital signature need to be generated)
- protobuf 2.4.1 for protobuff
- protobuf-c 0.15 for protobuff and these are dependencies libraries....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [{Makefile Error} "commands commence before first target. Stop."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238223/makefile-error-commands-commence-before-first-target-stop)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a target in the Makefile. The `make` supposes the following general structure:

```
target: depencies
    commands
```

Try the following:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_XSLT=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\" -DUNIX_SOCKETS -DXML_SECURITY -DDEBUG
LDFLAGS= -lcrypto -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -I/usr/local/include/xmlsec1 -lxmlsec1 -lprotobuf-c


fileClient:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) src/main.c src/file1.c src/file3.pb-c.c -o   fileClient
```

Comment: no i didnot defined... actually i dont know more about makefile... i m new for this...

Comment: acc to your answer i defined target in make file ... now error is changed... now it is showing collect2: ld returned 1 exit status for make file  & lots of warning is showing like undefined reference...

Comment: @user2309820 It seems like a linker issue. Please be sure that all decencies are installed, and paths are set correctly.